# accessing the return value of function that was bound to an event (tkinter)

Tags: python, events, tkinter, bind

Basically, what I've done is bound a click event to a function.  For example:

```
self.button1.bind("<Button-1>",self.chooseDice)
```

What I want now is to access the result of `chooseDice()` in another function.  What is the best way to go about doing that?

```
class GraphicsInterface:

    #we want to initialize the game board here, set up the dice and buttons
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry("720x500")

        #buttons under each die
        self.clicked=[] #empty list to collect all the buttons that were clicked (see chooseDice function)
        self.button1 = Button(self.window, text="Dice 1", width=13) #create the button object
        self.button1.place(x=60, y=160)  
        #bind button click event to a function (chooseDice())
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>",self.chooseDice)

        self.button2 = Button(self.window, text="Dice 2", width=13)
        self.button2.place(x=185, y=160)
        self.button2.bind("<Button-1>",self.chooseDice)

    #using the event as an argument, append the text to the clicked list
    def chooseDice(self, event):
        self.clicked.append(event.widget.cget('text'))
        self.diceList=[] #create a new empty list
        for i in range(len(self.clicked)):
            self.diceList.append(int(self.clicked[i][5])) #get just the int value of the last character (i.e. the dice number)
        self.deactivate(event.widget)  #deactivate the button
        return self.diceList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already doing what you need to do. Your example code sets `self.diceList` to some value. Anywhere else in your code you can directly use `self.diceList`.

By the way -- you're writing code that is going to be hard to maintain over time. For example, what if you change the dice label to "Dice One" or simply "One" rather than "Dice 1"? Or, as your app progresses you might want graphical images instead of text on the buttons. You'll have to modify the code that parses the button name. You are essentially encoding information in a button label which is not a good idea.

A simple solution, that also makes your `chooseDice` method simpler and easier to understand, is to pass in the dice number in the callback. For example:

```
self.button1.configure(command=lambda btn=self.button1: self.chooseDice(btn, 1))
```

The above passes two parameters to the `chooseDice` method: the button instance (so you can disable it) and the button number (so you don't have to parse the button name to get it)

This also allows you to create your dice in a loop rather than hard-coding multiple copies of the same block of code. Here's a complete working example:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GraphicsInterface:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry("720x500")
        self.clicked=[] 
        self.buttons = []

        for n in range(1, 3):
            btn = Button(text="Button " + str(n))
            btn.configure(command=lambda btn=btn, n=n: self.chooseDice(btn, n))
            btn.pack()
            self.buttons.append(btn)

        btn = Button(text="Go!", command=self.go)
        btn.pack()
        self.window.mainloop()


    def go(self):
        print "buttons:", self.clicked
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        '''Reset all the buttons'''
        self.clicked = []
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.configure(state="normal")

    def chooseDice(self, widget, number):
        self.clicked.append(number)
        widget.configure(state="disabled")

app = GraphicsInterface()
```

Finally, some last bits of advice:

Don't use `place`, it makes your GUIs harder to create, and they won't react well to changes in window size, changes in font, changes in platform, etc. Use `pack` and `grid` instead. Also, don't create fixed-width buttons. Again, this is to better handle changes in fonts. There are times when you want fixed width buttons, but it doesn't look like your code has any reason to use them.

Finally, I don't know what you're actually trying to accomplish, but usually if you're using buttons to track state (is this thing pressed or not?) you want to use checkboxes (pick N of N) or radiobuttons (pick 1 of N).  You might want to consider switching to those instead of to buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you input!  However, even with your approach, my problem still persists.  Firstly, I can't use 'self.diceList' anywhere else in my code as you said.  If I try, it just says AttributeError: 'GraphicsInterface' object has no attribute 'diceList'.  Basically, what I need to do is pass a list of names of the buttons that are clicked to my actual application class but I can't figure out how to do this because the I can't call my 'chooseDice' function with conventional parameters, right?  Isn't there some method for a button that tells me if a button was clicked?

Comment: @sq1020: you are failing to understand how my code works. It passes in the name of the widget and the dice number. You can store it however you want. My code stores the number in self.clicked. You can just as easily store the widget names, widget text, or widget objects themselves. Don't just blindly copy my code, learn from it. It shows you how to pass any information you want to your method. What information you pass, and what you do with that information is totally up to you.

Comment: @sq1020: Here's what you need to do: Add `self.diceList = []` in the constructor, and `self.diceList.append(widget.cget("text"))` in the `chooseDice` method. Also, put `self.diceList = []` in the `reset` method. It's just that simple.

Comment: I understand your code and I can pass the `self.clicked` list fine.  The problem I'm having though is that when I try to access the list in another class, it returns a blank list i.e. it doesn't wait for the user to click.  It just takes the original `self.clicked=[]`.  Any tips on how to make my application class wait until the list contains at least three items for example or something like that?  Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @sq1020: unfortunately I can't offer any other suggestions. There are no technical limitations, you simply have bugs in your code. Without seeing your code it's impossible to see what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for including the lambda command suggestion! I've been trying to find a way to pipe all event handling to a separate class's `process_event` method with the event name as a string (e.g. `command=lambda: self.coordinator.process_event('Help')`), but I couldn't figure out how to pass in an argument with command. Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Refactor.  Split this into two functions.

One returns the proper result, usable by other objects.

The other is bound to a GUI control, and uses the proper result to activate and deactivate GUI objects.

Indeed, you should **always** do this.  You should always have functions that do normal Python stuff, work correctly without the GUI and can be unit tested without the GUI.  Then you connect this working "model" to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

just add a `self.result` attribute to your class and set it at `chooseDice()`