# Tkinter: Get return value from a callback using a class method?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm attempting to follow the good advice from other related questions by avoiding using a global variable etc. I wrote a class method to handle the callback function for a TK `Button` widget. The function is supposed to return a path variable from a `Treeview` node. I can print the path from the function and it has what I need, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to return that back to my main function. I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7. Needless to say, I'm a beginner.

How do I get my path from `setdir()` back to `MAIN`, or how do I access that value?

Here's the class method, things I was unsure about or didn't help are commented out.

```
class sel_dir():

    #@classmethod
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = None
        self.node = None
        self.getbutton()

    def getbutton(self):
        Button(dirbrowse, command=self.setdir, text="SELECT").grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)
        #return self.path

    def setdir(self):
        self.node = tree.focus()
        if tree.parent(self.node):
            self.path = os.path.abspath(tree.set(self.node, "fullpath"))
            if os.path.isdir(self.path):
                print "PATH from sel_dir.setdir = ", self.path
                dirbrowse.destroy()
                return self.path
```

Here's the trimmed down `Main` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
import os
import glob

from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

def MAIN():
    global dirbrowse, tree

    dirbrowse = Tk()
    tree = Treeview(dirbrowse)

    # Get path from button click
    result = sel_dir()

    #print result.path

    # Just for debugging
    print vars(result)

    dirbrowse.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return anything to the main  function—it didn't call `result.setdir()`, `dirbrowse.mainloop()` did. After the button is selected and `setdir()` is called, it will be stored in `result.path`. You either need to make `setdir()` do more, or periodically check the value of `result.path`. You can do the latter by using the universal widget [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method.

Comment: your answer doesn't make sense. When I instantiate result=sel_dir(), _init_ calls getbutton which waits for click and then calls setdir which gets the path, it all works. What do you mean "do more"? I don't understand how after() matters, what's left to check for? I have my result I just need to send it back up the chain :-) Thanks

Comment: That's not how event-driven GUI programs work. `getbutton()` **doesn't** wait for a click or any other event. When an event is detected in `dirbrowse.mainloop()` **it** calls the `command` function, if any, that was specified when the associated `Button` was created,

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but it still leaves a lot to the imagination as far as how to make it work.

Comment: sdproto: Yes, it can be difficult to switch to [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) from the usual procedural or structured programming paradigm most of us are used to. If you can describe something you want to do after a path is selected, I'll see if I can work up a concrete example for you. It doesn't have to be what you ultimately really want to do, just something minimal.

Comment: thank you, it is a bit challenging. I think I might be on the edge of an epiphany, I need to re code and test, but I'm running out of steam tonight. I'll post back tomorrow either way. I found this other question with a similar dilemma I think might help too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209660/accessing-the-return-value-of-function-that-was-bound-to-an-event-python-tkinte

Comment: Yes, I can see why the answer to that question could be helpful—Bryan Oakley is one of the Tkinter experts around here.